# pythonian comparison: date.time from csv file to date.time from timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, csv, timestamp

In python I import a csv file with one datetime value at each row (2013-03-14 07:37:33)
and I want to compare it with the datetime values I obtain with timestamp.
I assume that when I read the csv the result is strings, but when I try to compare them in a loop with the strings from timestamp does not compare them at all without giving me an error at the same time.

Any suggestions?

```
csv_in = open('FakeOBData.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(csv_in)

for row in reader:
    date = row
    OBD.append(date)
```

.
.
.

```
for x in OBD:
    print x
    sightings = db.edge.find ( { "tag" : int(participant_tag)},{"_id":0}).sort("time")
    for sighting in sightings:
        time2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time)
        if x == time2:
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "but when I try to compare them in a loop with the strings from timestamp does not compare them at all without giving me an error at the same time"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [datetime.datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the strings into datetime objects.  You may also have to work out what time zone the date strings in your CSV are from and adjust for that.

`%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` should work as your format string:

```
x_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
if x_datetime == time2:
```

Or parse it when reading:

```
for row in reader:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parse it yourself with [datetime.datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) which should be fine if you know the format the date is in. If you do not know the format or want to be more robust I would advise you to use the parser from [python-dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) library, it has an awesome parser that is very robust.

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Then

```
import dateutil.parser
d = dateutil.parser.parse('1 Jan 2012 12pm UTC') # its that robust!
```